# DD WRT Firmware Beta from 2020, or Linksys or New Router? What to do?

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, dd-wrt

I have a Linksys router that has reached EOL and firmware has not been updated since 2018.
Subsequently I had intended to use DD-WRT on the router. Low and behold, the DD-WRT for mt router is in beta and the last beta release was in 2020 -- so I'd guess it's not THAT much more secure than the 2018 Firmware Data.

I am seeking your opinion on of I should

1. Buy a new router
2. Use DD-WRT 2020 Beta
3. Keep using the Linksys 2018 firmware that will never be upgraded

I do not like the Linksys Interface - the navigation makes no sense and I hate it.

I use port forwarded, reserved IPs for some devices and with I now need WiFi VLAN for cheap China camera that are untrusted. Pretty easy to VLAN those with DD-WRT

Any opinions and comments are appreciated and if a new router is suggested what make do you think is best. I do not want a lot of crap on the interface like most have these days and do not want to be forced to use a smartphone app or create any cloud accounts to configure the new router - IF I choose that router. Budget is $150

Thanks - appreciate your time

Comment: Order of priorities for me : 3, 2, 1. Option 2 may lead to 1 if it bricks the router.